# Clojure macro with try, catch

Tags: macros, exception, clojure, filenotfoundexception

This question was updated, but never answered and we have a very similar problem.
I would be grateful for some help regarding this question.

What we are trying to achive is to catch the java exception instead of the clojure exception.

[Clojure: try, catch macro that also closes any filestreams (not with-open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262720/clojure-try-catch-macro-that-also-closes-any-filestreams-not-with-open)

Comment: If this is *not* a duplicate, consider changing the title (in order to specify the need of catching java exceptions only).

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a Clojure exception. They're all just JVM exceptions. Given that, this is an exact duplicate of the post you linked to, since your entire question is "I have the same question as X".